# Setting delegate of UITextField in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, delegates

I am working in a standard `UIViewController` and added a `UITableView` in the `ViewDidLoad` method. Like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

_settingsTable =  [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+80, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[_settingsTable setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[_settingsTable setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
_settingsTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
_settingsTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:_settingsTable];

_settingsTable.dataSource = self;
_settingsTable.delegate = self;

_player01Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
_player01Cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_player01Cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Left player", nil) ];
_player01Cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AlfaSlabOne-Regular" size:12];
_player01Cell.textLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
_player01Cell.textLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
_player01Cell.textLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_player01Cell.textLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.0f);
_player01Cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_player01Cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

_aiPlayer01TextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _player01Cell.contentView.bounds.size.width-135, 30)];
_aiPlayer01TextField.center = CGPointMake(130+_aiPlayer01TextField.frame.size.width/2, _player01Cell.contentView.bounds.size.height/2);
_aiPlayer01TextField .placeholder = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Leftplayer", nil)];
_aiPlayer01TextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_aiPlayer01TextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_aiPlayer01TextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AlfaSlabOne-Regular" size:15];
_aiPlayer01TextField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
_aiPlayer01TextField.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
_aiPlayer01TextField.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_aiPlayer01TextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
_aiPlayer01TextField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.0f);
_aiPlayer01TextField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_aiPlayer01TextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[_aiPlayer01TextField resignFirstResponder];
[_player01Cell addSubview:_aiPlayer01TextField];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Everything is working as expected, except the delegate for the `UITextField`

I can touch the textfield and the keyboard pops up and works fine, but it does not go away after pressing Done. Nor will it go away after touching the view. I had it working before, but the the textfields were just placed on the main view, which was the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` But now, when I have the textfield in a custom cell, the delegate does not seem to work.

I also have this in code:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[_aiPlayer01TextField resignFirstResponder];
[_aiPlayer02TextField resignFirstResponder];
[_aiPlayer03TextField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[_aiPlayer01TextField resignFirstResponder];
[_aiPlayer02TextField resignFirstResponder];
[_aiPlayer03TextField resignFirstResponder];
return;
}


- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSLog(@"TOUCH");
[[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

How do I set the cell as the delegate for the textfield? Or should I set the tableView as delegate?

Thank you very much!